# How do I configure exim4 to send mail through a password protected ssl smtp mail server?

Tags: email, cron, smtp, mta

I'd like my cronjobs to be able to send mail from my home computer.  My servers configure exim4 like this:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames=''
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

However, at home, my ISP blocks mail sent directly via a firewall.  I have a password proteced ssl smtp server that I could route the mail through, but I have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to configure exim4 to make this work.  I'm hoping somebody can give me a configuration example where I can plug in the host name, user name, password, and "use ssl" to get it to send mail through a single smtp server.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I finally found a [detailed set of instructions by Tony Scelfo that actually work](http://blog.tonyscelfo.com/2009/07/13/use-smarthost-to-route-outgoing-exim4.html).  It appears that you have to use transport layer security (TLS) on port 587.  I have not gotten SSL SMTP to work.

First run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and use these config options:

- **General type of mail configuration:** mail sent by smarthost; received via SMTP or fetchmail
- **System mail name:** <your hostname>
- **IP-address to listen on for incoming SMTP connections:** 127.0.0.1
- **Other destinations for which mail is accepted:** <your hostname>
- **Machines to relay mail for:** <leave this blank>
- **IP address or host name of the outgoing smarthost:** mail.example.com::587
- **Hide local mail name in outgoing mail?**

  - Yes - all outgoing mail will appear to come from your gmail account
  - No - mail sent with a valid sender name header will keep the sender’s name
- **Keep number of DNS-queries minimal (Dial-on-Demand)?** No
- **Delivery method for local mail:** <choose the one you prefer>
- **Split configuration file into small files?** Yes (you need to edit one of the files next)

Then run `sudo vi /etc/exim4/passwd.client` and add the following lines for your mail host, and any aliases it has (found through `nslookup`).  Substitute <email address> and <password> with the account you want to route mail through):

```
mail.example.com:<email address>:<password>
mail.yourhosting.provider:<email address>:<password>
```

Once you edit the `passwd.client` file, run `sudo update-exim4.conf` which will integrate your changes into your Exim4 config.

Run `sudo /etc/init.d/exim4 restart` and make sure that the service stops and starts properly. If the service is unable to restart, something probably went wrong when you edited the `passwd.client` file.

If Exim4 restarted, go ahead and run `sudo tail -f /var/log/exim4/mainlog` to watch the mail logs. In a different window, send an email from your system and make sure that you see a record go by with`R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost H=gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com ... X=TLS-1.0:RSA_ARCFOUR_MD5:16` in it. The `X=TLS` means that the mail is being sent with transport layer security which is what you want.

Comment: No need to "split configuration file into small files" since `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` is a separate file either way.

Comment: Please note that specifying the SMTP port may not work with all mail servers. But `exim4` will use TLS anyway with the default SMTP port if the mailserver offers it. It can be checked looking at the `X=` information in `/var/log/exim4/mainlog`

Comment: Please, just point me to the correct direction. I don't want to duplicate some question. What if I want to all users to set their own stmp passwords in their HOME directories? Will exim4 look for various passwd.client? Tx

Comment: That sounds like a new question to me

Comment: @DrBeco If you have a specific question that is not specific to this question or answer, please [ask it as a question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: One thing to note is the *double colon* needed before the port number in "IP address or host name of the outgoing smarthost". It's easy to just type one out of habit.

Answer (score 8):

If your ISP requires authentication, you should set dc_smarthost to the mail server hostname and port combination your ISP uses, and dc_eximconfig_configtype to "smarthost" like so:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_smarthost='mail.example.com::587'
```

Then, you can add your credentials to `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` like so:

```
mail.example.com:username:password
```

Then, any mail sent via your exim4 server will be routed through this mail host.

Comment: In update-exim4.conf I put in two colons for the smarthost line, as in `dc_smarthost='mail.example.com::587'` and it made all the difference! Finally started sending mail through.

Comment: +1 This is a very common mistake I've seen on many tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

This works very well for me. My ISP uses port 25 and `dc_smarthost='myisp.mail.server:25'`
after changing this files and issue commands:

1. `update-exim4.conf`
2. `/etc/init.d/exim4 restart`

After I made a test to send an email through exim4 classic sample like:

```
echo "content of mail body with pt-br chars ação avião língua é essa em 1609." | mail -s "Confirmar 16DOM" my-user-in-isp@my-domain-url
```

And these flow ok to inbox of `my-user` in `my-domain-url`.

Answer (score 0):

The server-name in `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` have to be the canonical name **after** the name-resolution

example for:

```
dc_smarthost='securesmtp.t-online.de::587'
```

it is the value `sfwdallmx.t-online.de` from :

```
$ nslookup securesmtp.t-online.de
...
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   securesmtp.t-online.de
Address: 194.25.134.110
Name:   securesmtp.t-online.de
Address: 194.25.134.46
securesmtp.t-online.de  canonical name = sfwdallmx.t-online.de.
```

The file `passwd.client` looks like:

```
sfwdallmx.t-online.de:user:pwd
```