# Can exim be configured to send all emails externally?

Tags: server, email, hostname

**How do I configure exim4 to route all emails via a third-party SMTP server when the sender's domain, recipient's domain, and server hostname all match?**

I followed [this great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/282579/12864) and have `exim4` sending emails to addresses at other domains tested and working from an Ubuntu server. My only issue is that emails where both the sender and recipient share the same domain as the server hostname, they never leave the server (and this is the expected behavior).

For example, sending from test@example.com --> test@example2.com works fine, but sending from account1@example.com --> account2@example.com just routes the mail locally to `/var/mail/account2`, without passing through the third-party SMTP server.

I'm using Google Apps at my own domain and want to send emails from server@example.com to me@example.com from a machine with the hostname example.com.

I want to route them through Google's SMTP server so I see them in my other email clients. Is this possible?

Very similar questions (but for `postfix`) [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/272116/12864) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/347324/12864).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed the [guide linked in my question](https://askubuntu.com/a/282579/12864) you have about a dozen different 'routers' (simple text files) in `/etc/exim4/conf.d/router/`. The one to edit is  **200_exim4-config-primary**, like so:

`sudo nano /etc/exim4/conf.d/router/200_exim4-config_primary`

Down the bottom is a section 'smarthost:' that looks like this:

```
smarthost:
  debug_print = "R: smarthost for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = manualroute
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
  route_list = * DCsmarthost byname
  host_find_failed = defer
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  no_more
```

Remove the exclamation point and a space from the 'domains' line so that it looks like this:

```
  domains = +local_domains
```

That two-character edit was all it took to get everything working just now. Tested and working with Google Apps at my domain on Ubuntu Server 12.04 + Exim & thanks to Stefan for the clue!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me at first. I had to add an MX record to my DNS at Digital Ocean to get the messages off the host. They just looped and froze before I added the record.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the setting and use of

```
domainlist local_domains
```

You should find some uses in the access lists before things get interesting in the *router* section. My box at home has this one as *first* router:

```
    send_to_gateway:
      driver = manualroute
      domains = ! +local_domains
      transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
      route_list = * SMARTHOST
```

clarification: the following router will be applicable to all emails going to the contents of ˋlocal_domainsˋ

```
    send_to_gateway:
      driver = manualroute
      domains = +local_domains
      transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
      route_list = * SMARTHOST
```

The transport used is defined in the transport section of the exim config, you should already have one (possibly with a different name), which pushes your mail to other places. The route_list variable tells exim to push all mails of this router to the server SMARTHOST.

You should invest some time and read the fine exim manual. It will help with non-standard settings that are beyond what ubuntu's simplified configuration can do.

Comment: Are we both talking about `exim4` here? It is my understanding that the configuration file is automatically generated each time you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and I'm having trouble translating your hint above into something actionable in the set-up steps.

Comment: I don't use these configuration scripts, as they stop working once you want something a bit off the main path.

Comment: I've downvoted your answer as I'm unable to 'guess' what to do with it and my twelve router files (I have searched through them - `send_to_gateway:` isn't there). If you have a complete answer and are withholding it for some reason, please go ahead and post it. Thanks for taking the time to type a reply but I'm afraid I have no clue what to do with it yet.

Comment: Thanks, I have this working finally. Are you using Ubuntu + exim4? I ask because he strings `domainlist local_domains` or `send_to_gateway:` do not exist in any of my routers. `domains = ! +local_domains` does though, and this was the clue I needed. I'll post what worked as a new answer to make it easier for noobs like me to figure it out...

Comment: First thing I did with exim4 on the debian box I had, was to get exim ignore the split files and use a single configuration file. Much easier to handle for humans :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add your host to the `dc_relay_domains` config parameter like:

```
dc_relay_domains='example.com'
```

And remove `!` sign before `+local_domains` in `dnslookup_relay_to_domains` from `router/200_exim4-config_primary` or `exim4.conf.template` if you don't use split configuration (`dc_use_split_config='false'`) to looks like:

```
dnslookup_relay_to_domains:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup_relay_to_domains for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
  no_more
```

Or simply remove `!` from `dnslookup` section to send everything outside:

```
dnslookup:
  debug_print = "R: dnslookup for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = +local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  same_domain_copy_routing = yes
```